# Undefined method, wrong association or call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to make cumulative show.html for each user, that displays some data from 4 different models. Those tables:

[image: fragment of database model image]

Problem is that I dont know how to call data from Websites table for each Button. With displaying Buttons' data there is no problem.
That part of html should looks something like this:

```
<% if @profile.buttons.any? %>
  <ul>
  <% @buttons.each do |button| %>
    <li>
    <%= button.website.name %>
    <%= link_to button.user_website_url, button.user_website_url %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
<% else %>
  <p>None websites added. Please finish your profile creation.</p>
<% end %>
```

Models:

```
class Website < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :buttons
 mount_uploader :logo, LogoUploader
 validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
 validates :logo, presence: true
end

class Button < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
  belongs_to :website
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :website
  validates :description, length: { maximum: 140 }
  validates :user_website_url, presence: true, length: { maximum: 200 }
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :buttons, :dependent => :destroy
  #...
end
```

User Controller:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @profile = @user.profile
  @buttons = @profile.buttons
end
```

At this state of everything I'm getting an error:

> undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

So, what is wrong with this? I've tried many variations of associations and I'm getting either the error I put above or that no Id is passing (wrong query) for each website (that I also didn't know how to deal with).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably due to a button that has no associated website. See the line:

```
<%= button.website.name %>
```

If one of the buttons has a `website_id` of `nil`, calling the method `name` on the nil value would produce the error you see.

Comment: thanks, that was it. kingguy's .try( application allowed me to check that somewhere in my buttons table there was an old record without website_id. interestingly it wasn't record for button displayed for checked user.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with the following code, `button.website` returns nil,and nil dosen't have a method `name`:

```
<%= button.website.name %>
```

to fix it ,just use try:

```
<%= button.try(:website).try(:name) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line raising the error `<%= button.website.name %>`

`.name` is not getting any value because button has no any associated website and that's why it returns `nil:NilClass` as an error.